# ASP.NET Client Validation Javascript Partially Rendering

Tags: asp.net-2.0, client-side-validation

This is happening on my development machine and the same codebase is working in production. So I believe this to be an IIS/Framework issue. It affects all pages.

On both servers, the Page_Validators are setup correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired"),
document.getElementById("ValidatorCheckPostDateRequired"),
document.getElementById("ValidatorCheckPostDateFormat"),
document.getElementById("ValidatorCheckNumberRequired"),
document.getElementById("ValidatorCheckTotalRequired"),
document.getElementById("ValidatorCheckTotalFormat"));
// -->
</script>
```

However, on my development machine it does not render the script block that sets the validation properties:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired = document.all ? document.all["ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired"] : document.getElementById("ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired");
ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired.controltovalidate = "txtPayer";
ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired.errormessage = "<br>Insurance Payer Is Required";
ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired.display = "Dynamic";
ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ValidatorInsurancePayerRequired.initialvalue = "";
.
. all other Page Validators
.
// -->
</script>
```

I have tried running aspnet_regiis -c to reinstall the validation scripts. Failing that I tried that with a -e (remove) followed by -i (install).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What versions of .NET/IIS are you running?  If this is a 2.0 implementation, try putting this in your web.config in the system.web section and see what happens:

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
```

Does this happen if you run using the ASP.Net Development Server?

Also, if tracing is enabled in development, try disabling it.

Short of these few suggestions, I'd really need a lot more info on your environments in order to assist further.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, these settings were already configured as you stated. The Target Framework for the web app is .NET Framework 2.0 and my build path is to a folder mapped to a virtual directory in IIS 6. It does work if I run within the debugger though.

Comment: If you go to the IIS Manager and view your App Pools are both prod and dev set to the same app pool configuration?  I think I've also seen a similar client side framework failure when the application pool's mode is set to classic instead of integrated...

Comment: App Pool is default and both production and dev are integrated. I have a workaround so it's not a 'hot' issue for me now, more a curiosity that can wait. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's your workaround?  I'm pretty attached to you solving this by now :)